# High Side P Channel MOSFET damaged after turn off

Tags: power, mosfet, switches

The circuit below is a power switch controlled by a push button. Basically, the switch (Q1) is controlled by a On/Off IC controller.

During testing on the real circuit, a DC Electronic Load is connected on Vout (as load) and a DC power supply is connected to the input (Vin).

When the IC (U1) turn off the load, the P channel transistor is damaged in the following conditions:

- DC electronic load (connected at Vout): 2A
- DC Power Supply (connected at Vin): 24V (max 4A)

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

[image: Power switch using a ON/OFF IC controller and P MOSFET]

Edit: after adding a 40V 15A Schottky diode (SK154-TP) parallel to the load, the following test were performed:

1. 1A load with 24V input
2. 2A load with 24V input
3. 3A load with 24V input

Below the voltage on load during the turn on/off of the transistor.

[image: Output voltage with 1A load with 24V input]
[image: Output voltage with 2A load with 24V input]
[image: Output voltage with 3A load with 24V input]

Below the setup:

[image: Setup]

Performing the same testing (3 cases) without C1 and R2 = 0 the results on Vout

[image: Vout with 1A load without C1 and R2=0]
[image: Vout with 2A load without C1 and R2=0]
[image: Vout with 3A load without C1 and R2=0]

Comment: What is the load? If it is inductive, the current can't stop immediately and causes voltage spike on the transistor- in fact raises the voltage over D ans S until breakdown. Just in case, inductive load may be relay, motor, solenoid, speaker, etc.

Comment: Hi Gregory, Thanks for your comment. The load is a DC Electronic Load in "CC mode" (http://www.prodigit.com/product_c_3.php?button_num=g11&this_cname=&folder_id=42&cnt_id=121&orderby=1). I'm not sure about the inductance of this equipment. If this is the case, could you suggest a protection circuit? Thanks

Comment: Ok, CC mode is almols like an inductor. You have to add a serious diode with anode on the GND and cathode on the output. The current then will flow through it without damaging the transistor

Comment: I add a Schottky Diode as you suggested, but still damaged. Do you think a MBRS140 is a serious diode? https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MB/MBRS140.pdf. Thanks again

Comment: It says 1A, you need 2A, so put a 4A diode

Comment: And pu scope on the output, understand what's going on with the voltage there

Comment: I recommend adding links to datasheets for the MOSFET and the driver IC.

Comment: I add a Schottky Diode 40V 15A (SK154-TP) and did the following test: 1) 1A load and transistor OK, 2) 2A load and transistor OK but the temperature increase (put the finger on IC), 3) 3A load and the transistor damaged. Thanks for the suggestions. I will edit the post with scope pictures in these test cases.

Comment: OK, i will wait. Please specify on what component the temperature rises, i only expect the diode. Also maybe you can upload a photo of your setup.

Comment: The temperature rises on the transistor when turn off. I will upload setup pictures.

Comment: Oh, i known what is your problem. Remove the capacitor. And make the resistor between the gate and driver like 100r or even 0. You must close the transistor as quick as you can, otherwise the current times voltage is too high- power that heats it up exists for too long. Keep the diode, of course. In case your transistor's gate voltage is limited, make sue you get the maximum out of it.

Comment: The high voltage is disappear after change the circuit according with your suggestions. Now, the circuit turn on and off as quick as possible (please, refer to picture in post). If we want to keep the original idea of C1 to increase the voltage during the circuit is turn on, do you have a suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think you need it. Actually, i never saw such capacitor, doesn't look a good idea. Turning on only depends on how fast you charge the gate, which now seems pretty fast.

Comment: Gregory, thanks for your comment and suggestions. About the capacitor, the idea is to control the turn-on speed of the load switch (as suggested on http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND9093-D.PDF). I let you know, that performing additional (random) testing, the transistor is damaged again (around 3.5A) when is turn off :(((

Comment: Alright, i would argue that the capacitor does exactly the opposite of what you think. It makes the transistor open slowly, so the inrush current is limited. In that case you cannot just blindly use it, you must understand exactly all implications and be extremely careful. You saw the heat on the transistor, obviously it's not the way. Now, as i said before, the VGS, the gate voltage is limited. So you have to change the resistors again, and next time pay attention on that. So please, put R1 10k and R2 2k.

Comment: Upss, I will change the resistors. I will perform other testing and let you know later. Thanks Gregory.

Comment: Good luck! Don't forget to vote up the answer, moderators are mean :)

Comment: Hi again Gregory. I was traveling. Thanks for your suggestions. The circuit is working under the defined test conditions. PS: I still cannot vote up :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, CC mode is almols like an inductor. You have to add a serious diode with anode on the GND and cathode on the output. The current then will flow through it without damaging the transistor.

Upd: Oh, i known what is your problem. Remove the capacitor. And make the resistor between the gate and driver like 100r or even 0. You must close the transistor as quick as you can, otherwise the current times voltage is too high- power that heats it up exists for too long. Keep the diode, of course. In case your transistor's gate voltage is limited, make sue you get the maximum out of it.

Upd: It's still gets burned, but now there is no power or overvoltage on the drain. There is still overvoltage on the gate. Change the resistors so they will be still much smaller than the initial 100k, and at the same time will not drive the gate beyond it's absolute maximum rating. Change R1 to 10k and R2 to 2k.